# Updating driver url in a while loop - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a small function that needs to click on a page, execute the function get_data - this works, click on the next page, perform get_data click the button move to the next page check that the button "next page" exists and repeat this process.

So far all is good, but I just can get to update the driver url.

```
PATH = '/Applications/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

def moving_pages():
    driver.get('https://link-page-1')
    while driver.find_element_by_class_name('next-page-btn'):
        button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next-page-btn')
        button.click()
        time.sleep(4)
        get_data(driver.current_url)
        driver = driver.current_url
```

If I execute this I cannot update the driver because it is out of the scope. If I put the driver inside the while loop, the while loop will be False and will not execute.

What is a work around to get the next page, update the driver, check that the button "next-page-btn" is present execute get_data(current_page) and move on to the next.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know **driver** is out of scope in while loop because python considerd it as local variable/function.
So, to avoid that add **global driver** inside moving pages like:

```
PATH = '/Applications/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

    def moving_pages():
        global driver
        driver.get('https://link-page-1')

        while driver.find_element_by_class_name('next-page-btn'):
            button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next-page-btn')
            button.click()
            time.sleep(4)
            get_data(driver.current_url)
            driver = driver.current_url
```

Comment: Hmm,
I still get the following error: requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?

Comment: To the last line of code I tried adding 'https://www.' +, so it becomes: driver = 'https://www.' + driver.current_url. This still doesn't work.

Comment: add https://    or   http://     before link url